# Publish Site using SBT

Tags: scala, deployment, sbt, publish

I have an SBT project using SBT 0.13.2.  I am using the awesome sbt-site plugin to generate a pamflet site.

What is the best way using SBT to get the generated sbt-site onto a remote server for others to access?

We have this already setup and working wonderfully using Maven and WEBDAV.

I am hoping that there is a simple answer, barring creating my own sbt tasks.

Comment: I think ghpages is the only way to push currently, albeit that's just because it was the only push mechanism I needed.

The "spec" is open to implement an alternative push mechanism.  Are you using SSH or SVN/WEBDAV?  If so, there would need to be such a beast in the sbt-site world for this.

Comment: Oh, also, feel free to open a ticket to mark the request.  It could be someone else wants to write the synch task, or at least this lets folks know someone would find it useful.

Comment: Thanks.  I created a simple Webdav publish to my build.  It is pretty simple, wraps Sardine as the webdav client.  Perhaps I could contribute?  My only issue is that I wouldn't know how to tie it in the right way, I have a custom task to publish-webdav

Comment: noplay, @jsuereth could either of you post an answer so this question doesn't show up on unanswered list, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create my own SBT WEBDAV plugin to do the publishing.  If people are interested in what I did, feel free to contact me (note: unclear on how to post contact info on here).

It wasn't hard, but rather a pain.  I would love to open source it, but that would take time I don't have presently :(